# How to update the parameters of LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates

Tags: android, android-location, fusedlocationproviderapi

Developing an application where user location is tracked and distance is calculated from the destination. Now as location tracking is kind of heavy process, iam using ***LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY*** when the distance from destination is large than a particular threshold value. When the User approcahes destination, ***LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY*** mode will be used. Also the ***INTERVAL*** and ***FASTEST_INTERVAL*** will change accordingly.

What is the best way to change the parameter of

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
        mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

I've to change ***mLocationRequest*** parameters based on the current distance of the User from the destination.

Iam thinking of **stopping the location updates and then starting again with new parameters**. Is it the correct way?

Refer: [Receiving Location Updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, did you find a solution?

Comment: @stivaugoin No, till now no success...

Comment: I found that stopping the location updates and then starting again with new parameters seems to be the only way. But be aware that you will receive a location update immediately after restarting.